# How do i get json value

Tags: php, ajax, json

```
  error:function(response)
            {
                alert("e"+typeof response+"     "+Object.keys(response).length+"   "+"   "+response.txt);
            } /*use console.log*/
```

This is my error callback function in ajax post method.

I am returning data from php as follows

```
   die('{"status":0,"txt":"Email Already Exists"}');
```

It is valid json and i checked with `jsonlint`. [But i have doubt with this die statement validity too]

I am getting the alert as follows

```
    eobject     21     undefined
```

Yes, It is JSON Object. 21 characters are totally in the keys[Not sure whether my assumption is correct]. But how `response.txt` is undefined. If i print `response` it says `object object`.

But i din't see any response in Net tab of chrome under my php file. Actually ajax callback is in my html page. die code is from my php page.

Please correct me if i am wrong.How to get my JSON values.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Yes!! And It is not needed here. When i use in my js file, i get an exception

Comment: You have to execute `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");` in PHP or `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for `error`:

```
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

The variable you have called `response` is not the response, it is a [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

You need to read the response from it (because you don't have the response in a handy variable already) and parse it manually (because jQuery won't automatically parse error messages as JSON even if you set the `dataType` property or the `Content-Type` header).

```
error: function (jqXHR) {
    var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
    console.log(response);
}
```

---

I'd rethink your approach though. An internal server error is a poor way to communicate this type of error to the user. I can't think of a suitable HTTP status code to describe the error your message implies, so I'd return `200 OK` and leave the `success` function to parse the error message from the response.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting `unexpected end of token error at the first line of my html page which doctype` if i add `JSON.parse` method.

Comment: @GopsAB — Then either the `die` function from your code isn't being called, you're outputting HTML before you die with the JSON error message, you've put the wrong URL in, or the HTTP server is overriding your error message and showing its default one because you died (which would be solved by taking the advice in the final paragraph of this answer).

Comment: I don't understand `outputting html before die`. I am getting some responses without `JSON.parse` method. This is what confusing me

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` is what i am getting in the console

Comment: I just seen some SO posts. I copied the same string and parsed successfully in the console with JSON.parse method

Comment: And I don't get any errors in Mozilla. Instead JSON object gets printed in the screen. Why is this different behaviour in both browsers? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In php use json_encode and in JavaScript use JSON.parse

Comment: While `json_encode` is a better way to generate a JSON text in general, it won't help here because the string is already syntactically valid JSON. using `JSON.parse` don't help because `response` is clearly not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should set correct header and also use json_encode

```
<?php
$data = array('status'=>0, 'txt'=>'Email Already Exists');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: While `json_encode` is a better way to generate a JSON text in general, it won't help here because the string is already syntactically valid JSON. We can't see enough of the code to tell if it will be correctly parsed without explicitly giving the right content type. You're also changing it so that it outputs a successful response while the original code is trying to trigger an error.

Comment: I have updated my code to show that $data must be array, not string

Comment: That doesn't help though because the script was already outputting JSON.

Comment: Yes, it outputs JSON, but if the header is of json type jQuery (I assume he uses jQuery) will automatically parse the output as JSON, otherwise without the header you should explicitly parse the output

Comment: That makes the use os `json_encode` a red herring. You're also wrong since jQuery won't parse errors automatically. (You'd be right if we were talking about the `success` function).

Answer (score 0):

die function is equivalent to exit, and its parameter is used to provide a message before terminating the script. Its implementation is correct.
But you can't access an object property without parse the JSON string. response is a string, so you have to parse it.
Do the following:

- check response with alert() or console.log() in order to be sure that it is not been altered
- be sure you are including the required .js file to implement JSON.parse (json2.js) for browsers that do not support JSON natively
- after this, if it doesn't work yet, paste your javascript exception when you call JSON.parse

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` what i am getting in the console with the use of `JSON.parse` and i am using latest chrome version. I just checked in the console `JSON.parse` works there

Comment: Please, paste your ENTIRE sourcecode including how you are using JSON.parse function.